# How to omit DEBUG logs after changing log level of a logger from INFO to DEBUG before sending to an appender in log4j2

Tags: logging, filter, log4j, log4j2

I have a third party logger(audit-events) that is logging in INFO level. I want to convert these logs into DEBUG level and then omit them in stdout. Following is the code I wrote.

```
<AsyncLogger name="audit-events" level="${env:LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}" additivity="false">
     <AppenderRef ref="stdout-rewrite-info-to-debug"/>
</AsyncLogger>
```

```
<Rewrite name="stdout-rewrite-info-to-debug">
     <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
     <LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy logger="audit-events">
          <KeyValuePair key="INFO" value="DEBUG"/>
     </LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy>
     <Filters>
          <ThresholdFilter level="${env:LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
     </Filters>
</Rewrite>
```

${env:LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO} is a value that is injected at application startup. (e.g.- INFO, DEBUG) Default value would be INFO if it is not injected.

The log level conversion works fine. The problem is if I injected the LOGGING_LEVEL value as INFO, I shouldn't be getting any DEBUG logs in stdout but here I am getting the converted DEBUG logs. I thought the filter would do the trick and omit them but for some reason it didn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering in an `Appender` is performed **before** the `Appender#append` call. In the case of the `RewriteAppender` this means that the filter is applied before you modify the level of the event.

You need to put the filter further down the appender pipeline:

```xml
<Rewrite name="stdout-rewrite-info-to-debug">
     <AppenderRef ref="stdout" level="${env:LOGGING_LEVEL:-INFO}"/>
     <LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy logger="audit-events">
          <KeyValuePair key="INFO" value="DEBUG"/>
     </LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy>
</Rewrite>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. So in my original answer, the ThresholdFilter is applied before the LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy so the filter becomes useless. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the reason.